# javascript single-threaded , how asynchronous is implemented

Tags: javascript, v8

It is acknowledged that JavaScript is single-threaded ,but while i try the code below, when i use setTimeout and Promise, it's obviously that they runs asynchronously

```js
function testTimer(){
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log(2)},100)
}
function testLoop(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++){}
    console.log(3)
}
function testPromise(){
     return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        for(let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++){}
        resolve();
    })
}
console.log(1)
testTimer();
testLoop();
console.log(4)
testPromise().then(()=>{console.log(5)})
console.log(6)
```

If javascript is completely single-threaded, the console should print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in order. But the single threaded feature can only be seen in `testLoop()`, we can see that the use of `Promise` and `setTimeout` allow the code below run ahead, could someone please tell how's this achieved?

Comment: I think you might want to read about the JavaScript concurrency model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

In brief, your code is executed in a single thread. But once all the lines in your script have finished executing, the engine will wait for the next event to process, such as your setTimeout.

Then it processes the code for that event until it's done, and waits again for the next event.

Comment: "Single-threaded" doesn't mean that stuff needs to run synchronously. It still can be asynchronous ("out of order") by running on the *same* thread *later*. And that's exactly what is happening with your `setTimeout` and promise `then` callbacks.